# Is there a way to specify which edges can be used when resizing a sheet?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, resize

I wanted a sheet to be attached to the bottom edge of its parent window, so that I could still see the top part of the parent's content. I show it in the usual way in the parent's view controller.

```
@IBAction func clickShowSheet(_ sender: NSButton) {
  mySheet = MySheetController(windowNibName: "MySheet")
  view.window!.beginSheet(mySheet.window!, 
    completionHandler: {response in
       print(response == NSModalResponseOK ? "OK" : "Cancel")
       self.mySheet = nil
  })
}
```

To attach it to the bottom edge I implement the parent window's delegate method:

```
func window(_ window: NSWindow, willPositionSheet sheet: NSWindow, using rect: NSRect) -> NSRect {
   var rect = rect
   rect.origin.y = sheet.frame.size.height + 15
   return rect
}
```

The effect is satisfactory, tho' I'd like the animation to work the other way.

I also want the sheet to be resizable, so have left the checkbox in the nib on. Resizing by dragging a side is great: the sheet stays centred. The top edge can't be dragged, which would make sense if the sheet was at the top of its window, but the bottom edge *can* be dragged, leaving the sheet somewhere in the middle. I can make it spring back by implementing `windowDidEndLiveResize`. It looks silly. So what I need to know is, is there a way to enable/disable dragging of a particular edge?

Comment: Set `minSize` and `maxSize` of the sheet?

Comment: Sorry Willeke, that's not the solution.

Comment: @willeke In this particular case there's no need to change the width, so setting max, min and content widths to the same values disables dragging the side edges, but it would still be nice to change the height by dragging the top edge.

Comment: Usually sheets are attached to the top of the window. Maybe a child window is more like what you want.

Comment: A child window was my first thought, and I went quite a long way with it, even achieving some animation on its appearance. But somehow I couldn't get the modal behaviour required. It's in a document window, and should be modal for that window, but allow other documents to carry on as normal.

Comment: Using `beginSheet(...)` I got the modal behaviour for I wanted by *unchecking* the Document Modal style in the XIB. Seems non-intuitive, or is this an Xcode bug?

Answer (score -1):

Pass this as a prop if you are using spring bottom sheet.

```
blocking={false}
```